# Should I open the files in /home/user/ as root?

Tags: root

I do `su root` and then `nano -w /home/myusername/configfile` ... will this cause any problems ? Will it change the ownership of `configfile` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file does not exist yet then the new file will be owned by `root`.

If the file already exists, then it is just opened and the only attributes that change are atime and (if written to) mtime.

Comment: How do I own all files under /home/myusername ? is there a command for it ?

Comment: @l3gi0n `chown -R myusername: /home/myusername`

Comment: Would this also work: `sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /home/myusername/*`

Comment: @l3gi0n `chown` must be run by root. Your command is fine. Just seems to make little sense to exclude the home directory.

Comment: I see. many thank.